# No signature of method: save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

We are trying to upgrade a existing Grails 1.x application from 1.x to 2.x (current using 2.2.1).  One unit test is failing and I am stuck.  Here is what the test is doing...

Service -

```
def saveSomeData(myDomain) {
    return myDomain.save(flush:true)
}
```

Service Test -

```
void testShouldSaveAndReturnTrue() {
    def myDomainEmc = new ExpandoMetaClass(MyDomain)
    myDomainEmc.save = {flush -> true}
    myDomainEmc.initialize()
    myDomainEmc.metaClass = myDomainEmc
    assertTrue myTestService.saveSomeData(myDomainEmc)
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at this? [http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingDomains](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingDomains)

Answer (score 3):

From the error message, it looks like `save()` is being called somewhere without any arguments.  Try adding a no-arg `save()` method:

```
myDomainEmc.save = {-> true}
```

Also, I'd recommend using the Grails 2 `@Mock` annotation for mocking domain objects to save having to handle all the possible method calls with an `ExpandoMetaClass`.

Comment: @Mock(MyDomain), added to the Unittest class, solved the problem for me (grails 2.1.0):